# How to debug ANR crash logs

Tags: android, android-tv, leanback, android-anr-dialog

How to read the ANR crash logs

```
TraceHashCode: 43fa59baf2962ccc74bdf276b9cdd6fc21e9bb35    

----- pid 22452 at 2021-07-15 22:58:56 -----
Cmd line: com.testserver.test.tv.android.app
ABI: arm
Build type: optimized
Zygote loaded classes=4015 post zygote classes=8552
Intern table: 54311 strong; 3424 weak
JNI: CheckJNI is on; globals=766 (plus 3545 weak)
Libraries: /data/data/com.testserver.test.tv.android.app/lib-main/libc++_shared.so /data/data/com.testserver.test.tv.android.app/lib-main/libfb.so /data/data/com.testserver.test.tv.android.app/lib-main/libfbjni.so /data/data/com.testserver.test.tv.android.app/lib-main/libfolly_json.so /data/data/com.testserver.test.tv.android.app/lib-main/libglog.so /data/data/com.testserver.test.tv.android.app/lib-main/libglog_init.so /data/data/com.testserver.test.tv.android.app/lib-main/libjsc.so /data/data/com.testserver.test.tv.android.app/lib-main/libjscexecutor.so /data/data/com.testserver.test.tv.android.app/lib-main/libjsinspector.so /data/data/com.testserver.test.tv.android.app/lib-main/libreactnativeblob.so /data/data/com.testserver.test.tv.android.app/lib-main/libreactnativejni.so /data/data/com.testserver.test.tv.android.app/lib-main/libyoga.so /data/data/com.testserver.test.tv.android.app/lib/libAIVDash.so /data/data/com.testserver.test.tv.android.app/lib/libAIVHeuristics.so /data/data/com.testserver.test.tv.android.app/lib/libAIVMemoryAllocator.so /data/data/com.testserver.test.tv.android.app/lib/libAIVSecureRenderer.so /data/data/com.testserver.test.tv.android.app/lib/libATVPlaybackSmoothStream.so /system/app/testserverWebView/lib/arm/libwebviewextchromium.so /system/lib/libandroid.so /system/lib/libaudioeffect_jni.so /system/lib/libcompiler_rt.so /system/lib/libdrmframework_jni.so /system/lib/libjavacrypto.so /system/lib/libjnigraphics.so /system/lib/libmedia_jni.so /system/lib/librs_jni.so /system/lib/libsoundpool.so /system/lib/libwebviewchromium_loader.so /system/lib/libwebviewchromium_plat_support.so libjavacore.so (30)
Heap: 0% free, 122MB/123MB; 682509 objects
Dumping cumulative Gc timings
Start Dumping histograms for 148 iterations for concurrent mark sweep
ProcessMarkStack:   Sum: 2.718s 99% C.I. 0.006ms-45.871ms Avg: 6.123ms Max: 57.400ms
MarkConcurrentRoots:    Sum: 349.084ms 99% C.I. 0.005ms-6.700ms Avg: 1.179ms Max: 8.178ms
UpdateAndMarkImageModUnionTable:    Sum: 346.320ms 99% C.I. 0.816ms-9.052ms Avg: 2.340ms Max: 9.175ms
MarkRootsCheckpoint:    Sum: 195.511ms 99% C.I. 43us-14432us Avg: 660.510us Max: 47559us
SweepMallocSpace:   Sum: 134.367ms 99% C.I. 5us-7112us Avg: 453.942us Max: 11505us
ImageModUnionClearCards:    Sum: 63.988ms 99% C.I. 106us-4312us Avg: 216.175us Max: 7123us
ScanGrayZygoteSpaceObjects: Sum: 39.881ms 99% C.I. 445us-2581.249us Avg: 531.746us Max: 3622us
MarkNonThreadRoots: Sum: 28.422ms 99% C.I. 17us-682us Avg: 96.020us Max: 1153us
SweepZygoteSpace:   Sum: 27.015ms 99% C.I. 215us-3268.749us Avg: 360.200us Max: 4574us
ZygoteModUnionClearCards:   Sum: 26.815ms 99% C.I. 53us-2175us Avg: 178.766us Max: 4308us
SweepLargeObjects:  Sum: 23.106ms 99% C.I. 9.250us-617us Avg: 156.121us Max: 916us
MarkAllocStackAsLive:   Sum: 19.753ms 99% C.I. 30us-995us Avg: 133.466us Max: 1515us
ScanGrayAllocSpaceObjects:  Sum: 18.589ms 99% C.I. 0.304us-604us Avg: 62.800us Max: 973us
ReMarkRoots:    Sum: 17.900ms 99% C.I. 48us-543us Avg: 120.945us Max: 944us
SweepSystemWeaks:   Sum: 17.259ms 99% C.I. 11us-1039us Avg: 116.614us Max: 1125us
AllocSpaceClearCards:   Sum: 15.934ms 99% C.I. 0.336us-138us Avg: 26.915us Max: 612us
EnqueueFinalizerReferences: Sum: 14.808ms 99% C.I. 4us-890us Avg: 100.054us Max: 1989us
(Paused)ScanGrayImageSpaceObjects:  Sum: 13.359ms 99% C.I. 69us-902us Avg: 90.263us Max: 1039us
FinishPhase:    Sum: 13.205ms 99% C.I. 48us-493us Avg: 89.222us Max: 893us
ScanGrayImageSpaceObjects:  Sum: 12.102ms 99% C.I. 69us-426us Avg: 81.770us Max: 485us
(Paused)ScanGrayZygoteSpaceObjects: Sum: 4.901ms 99% C.I. 29us-1299.999us Avg: 65.346us Max: 1888us
(Paused)ScanGrayAllocSpaceObjects:  Sum: 4.552ms 99% C.I. 0.253us-152us Avg: 15.378us Max: 275us
SwapBitmaps:    Sum: 3.677ms 99% C.I. 12us-256us Avg: 24.844us Max: 672us
MarkingPhase:   Sum: 3.454ms 99% C.I. 12us-163us Avg: 23.337us Max: 183us
(Paused)PausePhase: Sum: 2.893ms 99% C.I. 11us-139us Avg: 19.547us Max: 205us
ProcessCards:   Sum: 2.437ms 99% C.I. 4us-49.918us Avg: 8.233us Max: 213us
PreCleanCards:  Sum: 2.307ms 99% C.I. 12us-41us Avg: 15.587us Max: 41us
ReclaimPhase:   Sum: 2.301ms 99% C.I. 8us-315us Avg: 15.547us Max: 469us
RevokeAllThreadLocalAllocationStacks:   Sum: 2.144ms 99% C.I. 6us-126us Avg: 14.486us Max: 172us
Sweep:  Sum: 1.499ms 99% C.I. 5us-89us Avg: 10.128us Max: 172us
ProcessReferences:  Sum: 1.127ms 99% C.I. 4us-32us Avg: 7.614us Max: 32us
MarkRoots:  Sum: 990us 99% C.I. 5us-12us Avg: 6.689us Max: 12us
InitializePhase:    Sum: 938us 99% C.I. 1us-81.499us Avg: 6.337us Max: 82us
RecursiveMark:  Sum: 765us 99% C.I. 3us-10us Avg: 5.168us Max: 10us
BindBitmaps:    Sum: 553us 99% C.I. 2us-11us Avg: 3.736us Max: 11us
SwapStacks: Sum: 304us 99% C.I. 1us-3us Avg: 2.054us Max: 3us
FindDefaultSpaceBitmap: Sum: 150us 99% C.I. 0.250us-2us Avg: 1.013us Max: 2us
UnBindBitmaps:  Sum: 145us 99% C.I. 250ns-3000ns Avg: 979ns Max: 3000ns
(Paused)ProcessMarkStack:   Sum: 113us 99% C.I. 250ns-3000ns Avg: 763ns Max: 3000ns
PreSweepingGcVerification:  Sum: 95us 99% C.I. 250ns-5000ns Avg: 641ns Max: 5000ns
Done Dumping histograms 
concurrent mark sweep paused:   Sum: 49.673ms 99% C.I. 190us-1890us Avg: 335.628us Max: 2985us
concurrent mark sweep total time: 4.131s mean time: 27.915ms
concurrent mark sweep freed: 280278 objects with total size 12MB
concurrent mark sweep throughput: 67847.5/s / 3MB/s
Start Dumping histograms for 36 iterations for partial concurrent mark sweep
ProcessMarkStack:   Sum: 10.356s 99% C.I. 0.101ms-697.856ms Avg: 95.894ms Max: 774.064ms
MarkRootsCheckpoint:    Sum: 4.844s 99% C.I. 1.174ms-457.727ms Avg: 67.280ms Max: 498.909ms
SweepMallocSpace:   Sum: 1.108s 99% C.I. 0.030ms-139.007ms Avg: 15.393ms Max: 161.471ms
UpdateAndMarkZygoteModUnionTable:   Sum: 1.072s 99% C.I. 13.409ms-90.496ms Avg: 29.796ms Max: 91.606ms
ScanGrayAllocSpaceObjects:  Sum: 725.306ms 99% C.I. 0.023ms-100.351ms Avg: 10.073ms Max: 112.148ms
ReMarkRoots:    Sum: 721.687ms 99% C.I. 1.688ms-115.968ms Avg: 20.046ms Max: 119.179ms
MarkConcurrentRoots:    Sum: 586.443ms 99% C.I. 0.027ms-153.599ms Avg: 8.145ms Max: 208.133ms
UpdateAndMarkImageModUnionTable:    Sum: 354.371ms 99% C.I. 1.515ms-49.168ms Avg: 9.843ms Max: 49.172ms
(Paused)ScanGrayObjects:    Sum: 229.932ms 99% C.I. 0.561ms-67.888ms Avg: 6.387ms Max: 78.238ms
SweepLargeObjects:  Sum: 220.739ms 99% C.I. 0.204ms-79.648ms Avg: 6.131ms Max: 87.340ms
EnqueueFinalizerReferences: Sum: 93.134ms 99% C.I. 0.013ms-35.328ms Avg: 2.587ms Max: 40.233ms
AllocSpaceClearCards:   Sum: 92.416ms 99% C.I. 2us-12751.999us Avg: 641.777us Max: 18712us
ScanGrayImageSpaceObjects:  Sum: 77.595ms 99% C.I. 0.090ms-29.088ms Avg: 2.155ms Max: 32.375ms
MarkAllocStackAsLive:   Sum: 60.493ms 99% C.I. 0.089ms-10.104ms Avg: 1.680ms Max: 11.257ms
MarkNonThreadRoots: Sum: 36.380ms 99% C.I. 45us-17215.999us Avg: 505.277us Max: 25914us
FinishPhase:    Sum: 33.168ms 99% C.I. 131us-11872us Avg: 921.333us Max: 13510us
SweepSystemWeaks:   Sum: 32.427ms 99% C.I. 52us-2975us Avg: 900.750us Max: 2975us
ImageModUnionClearCards:    Sum: 10.717ms 99% C.I. 119us-545.999us Avg: 148.847us Max: 598us
RevokeAllThreadLocalAllocationStacks:   Sum: 7.325ms 99% C.I. 18us-435us Avg: 203.472us Max: 435us
ReclaimPhase:   Sum: 7.048ms 99% C.I. 11us-4700us Avg: 195.777us Max: 5563us
ProcessReferences:  Sum: 5.488ms 99% C.I. 7us-1352us Avg: 152.444us Max: 1514us
ProcessCards:   Sum: 5.419ms 99% C.I. 6us-2961.999us Avg: 75.263us Max: 4552us
ZygoteModUnionClearCards:   Sum: 4.854ms 99% C.I. 46us-551.999us Avg: 67.416us Max: 711us
Sweep:  Sum: 4.831ms 99% C.I. 12us-2918us Avg: 134.194us Max: 3340us
ScanGrayZygoteSpaceObjects: Sum: 2.011ms 99% C.I. 34us-282us Avg: 55.861us Max: 292us
PreCleanCards:  Sum: 1.168ms 99% C.I. 20us-111us Avg: 32.444us Max: 111us
MarkingPhase:   Sum: 1.143ms 99% C.I. 22us-45us Avg: 31.750us Max: 45us
(Paused)PausePhase: Sum: 815us 99% C.I. 17us-36us Avg: 22.638us Max: 36us
SwapBitmaps:    Sum: 773us 99% C.I. 14us-91us Avg: 21.472us Max: 96us
MarkRoots:  Sum: 466us 99% C.I. 7us-132us Avg: 12.944us Max: 139us
RecursiveMark:  Sum: 185us 99% C.I. 3us-13us Avg: 5.138us Max: 13us
PreSweepingGcVerification:  Sum: 173us 99% C.I. 0.257us-155us Avg: 4.805us Max: 155us
BindBitmaps:    Sum: 145us 99% C.I. 2us-9us Avg: 4.027us Max: 9us
InitializePhase:    Sum: 115us 99% C.I. 2us-8us Avg: 3.194us Max: 8us
UnBindBitmaps:  Sum: 112us 99% C.I. 1us-13us Avg: 3.111us Max: 13us
(Paused)ProcessMarkStack:   Sum: 74us 99% C.I. 1us-5us Avg: 2.055us Max: 5us
SweepZygoteSpace:   Sum: 44us 99% C.I. 1us-3us Avg: 1.222us Max: 3us
FindDefaultSpaceBitmap: Sum: 36us 99% C.I. 0.250us-2us Avg: 1us Max: 2us
Done Dumping histograms 
partial concurrent mark sweep paused:   Sum: 1.616s 99% C.I. 6.974ms-168.800ms Avg: 44.910ms Max: 170.851ms
partial concurrent mark sweep total time: 20.698s mean time: 574.971ms
partial concurrent mark sweep freed: 1815419 objects with total size 197MB
partial concurrent mark sweep throughput: 87709.9/s / 9MB/s
Start Dumping histograms for 79 iterations for sticky concurrent mark sweep
MarkRootsCheckpoint:    Sum: 9.246s 99% C.I. 0.791ms-401.152ms Avg: 58.522ms Max: 439.888ms
ScanGrayAllocSpaceObjects:  Sum: 3.304s 99% C.I. 0.033ms-104.832ms Avg: 10.457ms Max: 140.464ms
FreeList:   Sum: 1.804s 99% C.I. 4.411us-10977.999us Avg: 597.213us Max: 40596us
ReMarkRoots:    Sum: 1.270s 99% C.I. 0.632ms-128.671ms Avg: 16.078ms Max: 130.067ms
ScanGrayImageSpaceObjects:  Sum: 470.715ms 99% C.I. 0.084ms-70.560ms Avg: 2.979ms Max: 82.755ms
ProcessMarkStack:   Sum: 423.929ms 99% C.I. 0.003ms-21.296ms Avg: 1.341ms Max: 30.520ms
MarkConcurrentRoots:    Sum: 362.074ms 99% C.I. 0.006ms-17.724ms Avg: 2.291ms Max: 20.867ms
SweepArray: Sum: 347.442ms 99% C.I. 0.135ms-28.187ms Avg: 4.398ms Max: 30.380ms
MarkNonThreadRoots: Sum: 280.631ms 99% C.I. 0.049ms-59.168ms Avg: 1.776ms Max: 231.122ms
(Paused)ScanGrayObjects:    Sum: 267.744ms 99% C.I. 0.498ms-13.535ms Avg: 3.389ms Max: 14.777ms
AllocSpaceClearCards:   Sum: 180.075ms 99% C.I. 2us-4794us Avg: 569.857us Max: 9842us
EnqueueFinalizerReferences: Sum: 105.740ms 99% C.I. 0.005ms-20.261ms Avg: 1.338ms Max: 21.882ms
SweepSystemWeaks:   Sum: 105.481ms 99% C.I. 0.104ms-10.582ms Avg: 1.335ms Max: 12.352ms
MarkingPhase:   Sum: 59.263ms 99% C.I. 353us-7686.499us Avg: 750.164us Max: 8187us
ImageModUnionClearCards:    Sum: 28.222ms 99% C.I. 121us-1445.500us Avg: 178.620us Max: 4227us
ResetStack: Sum: 21.819ms 99% C.I. 31us-8059.999us Avg: 276.189us Max: 12767us
RevokeAllThreadLocalAllocationStacks:   Sum: 15.839ms 99% C.I. 34us-752.499us Avg: 200.493us Max: 946us
ScanGrayZygoteSpaceObjects: Sum: 12.953ms 99% C.I. 33us-1203.500us Avg: 81.981us Max: 3849us
ZygoteModUnionClearCards:   Sum: 12.743ms 99% C.I. 47us-1014.500us Avg: 80.651us Max: 2937us
FinishPhase:    Sum: 8.535ms 99% C.I. 48us-1062.999us Avg: 108.037us Max: 1271us
PreCleanCards:  Sum: 4.878ms 99% C.I. 18us-1772.999us Avg: 61.746us Max: 2771us
ReclaimPhase:   Sum: 4.413ms 99% C.I. 11us-1030.250us Avg: 55.860us Max: 1046us
ForwardSoftReferences:  Sum: 2.949ms 99% C.I. 2us-1622.999us Avg: 37.329us Max: 2633us
ProcessReferences:  Sum: 2.885ms 99% C.I. 5us-501.249us Avg: 36.518us Max: 590us
ProcessCards:   Sum: 2.440ms 99% C.I. 7us-184us Avg: 15.443us Max: 451us
SwapBitmaps:    Sum: 2.109ms 99% C.I. 6us-702.499us Avg: 26.696us Max: 865us
(Paused)PausePhase: Sum: 1.668ms 99% C.I. 15us-35us Avg: 21.113us Max: 35us
UnBindBitmaps:  Sum: 920us 99% C.I. 3us-382.749us Avg: 11.645us Max: 550us
MarkRoots:  Sum: 699us 99% C.I. 6us-17us Avg: 8.848us Max: 17us
SwapStacks: Sum: 616us 99% C.I. 2us-261.749us Avg: 7.797us Max: 355us
BindBitmaps:    Sum: 329us 99% C.I. 2us-10us Avg: 4.164us Max: 10us
InitializePhase:    Sum: 267us 99% C.I. 2us-26us Avg: 3.379us Max: 26us
FindDefaultSpaceBitmap: Sum: 223us 99% C.I. 1us-8us Avg: 2.822us Max: 8us
RecordFree: Sum: 184us 99% C.I. 1us-6us Avg: 2.329us Max: 6us
(Paused)ProcessMarkStack:   Sum: 137us 99% C.I. 1us-4us Avg: 1.734us Max: 4us
PreSweepingGcVerification:  Sum: 54us 99% C.I. 250ns-1000ns Avg: 683ns Max: 1000ns
Done Dumping histograms 
sticky concurrent mark sweep paused:    Sum: 2.401s 99% C.I. 3.034ms-161.679ms Avg: 30.400ms Max: 165.470ms
sticky concurrent mark sweep total time: 18.353s mean time: 232.328ms
sticky concurrent mark sweep freed: 2986055 objects with total size 167MB
sticky concurrent mark sweep throughput: 162701/s / 9MB/s
Total time spent in GC: 43.184s
Mean GC size throughput: 6MB/s
Mean GC object throughput: 118781 objects/s
Total number of allocations 5811996
Total bytes allocated 392MB
Free memory 786KB
Free memory until GC 786KB
Free memory until OOME 133MB
Total memory 123MB
Max memory 256MB
Zygote space size 3MB
Total mutator paused time: 4.068s
Total time waiting for GC to complete: 1.024s

DALVIK THREADS (208):
"main" prio=5 tid=1 Native
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x74a8e000 self=0xb7406ed0
  | sysTid=22452 nice=-4 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0xb6f82000
  | state=S schedstat=( 43646025214 10389544342 33452 ) utm=3803 stm=561 core=0 HZ=100
  | stack=0xbe229000-0xbe22b000 stackSize=8MB
  | held mutexes=
  native: #00 pc 00012ac0  /system/lib/libc.so (syscall+28)
  native: #01 pc 000a98af  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art17ConditionVariable4WaitEPNS_6ThreadE+82)
  native: #02 pc 00282a13  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3artL12GoToRunnableEPNS_6ThreadE+786)
  native: #03 pc 00087571  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art12JniMethodEndEjPNS_6ThreadE+8)
  native: #04 pc 002645b7  /data/dalvik-cache/arm/system@framework@boot.oat (Java_android_os_Parcel_nativeWriteStrongBinder__JLandroid_os_IBinder_2+130)
  at android.os.Parcel.nativeWriteStrongBinder(Native method)
  at android.os.Parcel.writeStrongBinder(Parcel.java:579)
  at com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodManager$Stub$Proxy.finishInput(IInputMethodManager.java:646)
  at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.finishInputLocked(InputMethodManager.java:820)
  at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.checkFocusNoStartInput(InputMethodManager.java:1379)
  - locked <@addr=0x133a9c00> (a android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager$H)
  at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.checkFocus(InputMethodManager.java:1356)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewRootHandler.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:3401)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5604)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke!(Native method)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:984)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:779)

"Heap thread pool worker thread 0" prio=5 tid=2 Native (still starting up)
  | group="" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x0 self=0xb765ded0
  | sysTid=22458 nice=0 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0xb7667818
  | state=S schedstat=( 107341308 102632307 152 ) utm=10 stm=0 core=0 HZ=100
  | stack=0xb49cb000-0xb49cd000 stackSize=1020KB
  | held mutexes=
  native: #00 pc 00012ac0  /system/lib/libc.so (syscall+28)
  native: #01 pc 000a98af  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art17ConditionVariable4WaitEPNS_6ThreadE+82)
  native: #02 pc 002379b7  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art10ThreadPool7GetTaskEPNS_6ThreadE+50)
  native: #03 pc 0023795f  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art16ThreadPoolWorker3RunEv+54)
  native: #04 pc 0023819d  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art16ThreadPoolWorker8CallbackEPv+52)
  native: #05 pc 00016777  /system/lib/libc.so (_ZL15__pthread_startPv+30)
  native: #06 pc 00014627  /system/lib/libc.so (__start_thread+6)
  (no managed stack frames)

"Heap thread pool worker thread 1" prio=5 tid=3 Native (still starting up)
  | group="" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x0 self=0xb7669198
  | sysTid=22459 nice=0 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0xb765ff50
  | state=S schedstat=( 101241237 91383542 154 ) utm=7 stm=3 core=0 HZ=100
  | stack=0xb48cb000-0xb48cd000 stackSize=1020KB
  | held mutexes=
  native: #00 pc 00012ac0  /system/lib/libc.so (syscall+28)
  native: #01 pc 000a98af  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art17ConditionVariable4WaitEPNS_6ThreadE+82)
  native: #02 pc 002379b7  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art10ThreadPool7GetTaskEPNS_6ThreadE+50)
  native: #03 pc 0023795f  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art16ThreadPoolWorker3RunEv+54)
  native: #04 pc 0023819d  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art16ThreadPoolWorker8CallbackEPv+52)
  native: #05 pc 00016777  /system/lib/libc.so (_ZL15__pthread_startPv+30)
  native: #06 pc 00014627  /system/lib/libc.so (__start_thread+6)
  (no managed stack frames)

"Heap thread pool worker thread 2" prio=5 tid=4 Native (still starting up)
  | group="" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x0 self=0xb765f258
  | sysTid=22460 nice=0 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0xb7660608
  | state=S schedstat=( 117058692 122266919 164 ) utm=10 stm=1 core=1 HZ=100
  | stack=0xb47cb000-0xb47cd000 stackSize=1020KB
  | held mutexes=
  native: #00 pc 00012ac0  /system/lib/libc.so (syscall+28)
  native: #01 pc 000a98af  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art17ConditionVariable4WaitEPNS_6ThreadE+82)
  native: #02 pc 002379b7  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art10ThreadPool7GetTaskEPNS_6ThreadE+50)
  native: #03 pc 0023795f  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art16ThreadPoolWorker3RunEv+54)
  native: #04 pc 0023819d  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art16ThreadPoolWorker8CallbackEPv+52)
  native: #05 pc 00016777  /system/lib/libc.so (_ZL15__pthread_startPv+30)
  native: #06 pc 00014627  /system/lib/libc.so (__start_thread+6)
  (no managed stack frames)

"Signal Catcher" daemon prio=5 tid=5 Runnable
  | group="system" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x12c8e0a0 self=0xb765f890
  | sysTid=22461 nice=0 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0xb765e4e8
  | state=R schedstat=( 408445534 32821307 316 ) utm=15 stm=25 core=1 HZ=100
  | stack=0xb46c1000-0xb46c3000 stackSize=1012KB
  | held mutexes= "thread list lock" "mutator lock"(exclusive held)
  native: #00 pc 00004eac  /system/lib/libbacktrace_libc++.so (_ZN13UnwindCurrent6UnwindEjP8ucontext+23)
  native: #01 pc 0000362d  /system/lib/libbacktrace_libc++.so (_ZN9Backtrace6UnwindEjP8ucontext+8)
  native: #02 pc 002493bd  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art15DumpNativeStackERNSt3__113basic_ostreamIcNS0_11char_traitsIcEEEEiPKcPNS_6mirror9ArtMethodE+68)
  native: #03 pc 0022d6d7  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZNK3art6Thread4DumpERNSt3__113basic_ostreamIcNS1_11char_traitsIcEEEE+146)
  native: #04 pc 002369fb  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art10ThreadList14DumpForSigQuitERNSt3__113basic_ostreamIcNS1_11char_traitsIcEEEE+142)
  native: #05 pc 0021c363  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art7Runtime14DumpForSigQuitERNSt3__113basic_ostreamIcNS1_11char_traitsIcEEEE+66)
  native: #06 pc 002224e1  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art13SignalCatcher13HandleSigQuitEv+804)
  native: #07 pc 00222baf  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art13SignalCatcher3RunEPv+318)
  native: #08 pc 00016777  /system/lib/libc.so (_ZL15__pthread_startPv+30)
  native: #09 pc 00014627  /system/lib/libc.so (__start_thread+6)
  (no managed stack frames)

"JDWP" daemon prio=5 tid=6 WaitingInMainDebuggerLoop
  | group="system" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x12c910a0 self=0xb766c530
  | sysTid=22462 nice=0 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0xb766c2e8
  | state=S schedstat=( 3018693 4814154 9 ) utm=0 stm=0 core=2 HZ=100
  | stack=0xb45bf000-0xb45c1000 stackSize=1012KB
  | held mutexes=
  native: #00 pc 0003e084  /system/lib/libc.so (__pselect6+20)
  native: #01 pc 00015f17  /system/lib/libc.so (select+60)
  native: #02 pc 002886ab  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art4JDWP12JdwpAdbState15ProcessIncomingEv+182)
  native: #03 pc 0018ec61  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art4JDWP9JdwpState3RunEv+328)
  native: #04 pc 00190083  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art4JDWPL15StartJdwpThreadEPv+10)
  native: #05 pc 00016777  /system/lib/libc.so (_ZL15__pthread_startPv+30)
  native: #06 pc 00014627  /system/lib/libc.so (__start_thread+6)
  (no managed stack frames)

"ReferenceQueueDaemon" daemon prio=5 tid=7 Waiting
  | group="system" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x12c5c7c0 self=0xb766cc50
  | sysTid=22463 nice=0 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0xb766d228
  | state=S schedstat=( 252811777 184338312 711 ) utm=16 stm=9 core=0 HZ=100
  | stack=0xb44b7000-0xb44b9000 stackSize=1036KB
  | held mutexes=
  at java.lang.Object.wait!(Native method)
  - waiting on <0x2133bb94> (a java.lang.Class<java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue>)
  at java.lang.Daemons$ReferenceQueueDaemon.run(Daemons.java:135)
  - locked <0x2133bb94> (a java.lang.Class<java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue>)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)

"FinalizerDaemon" daemon prio=5 tid=8 Waiting
  | group="system" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x12c5c820 self=0xb766d5f0
  | sysTid=22464 nice=0 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0xb766dbe8
  | state=S schedstat=( 889591787 765994232 1294 ) utm=67 stm=21 core=0 HZ=100
  | stack=0xb05fe000-0xb0600000 stackSize=1036KB
  | held mutexes=
  at java.lang.Object.wait!(Native method)
  - waiting on <0x0ea6263d> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue)
  at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:422)
  at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:101)
  - locked <0x0ea6263d> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue)
  at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:72)
  at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.run(Daemons.java:175)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)

"FinalizerWatchdogDaemon" daemon prio=5 tid=9 Sleeping
  | group="system" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x12c5c880 self=0xb766de30
  | sysTid=22465 nice=0 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0xb766e450
  | state=S schedstat=( 4261922 12510768 38 ) utm=0 stm=0 core=3 HZ=100
  | stack=0xa534b000-0xa534d000 stackSize=1036KB
  | held mutexes=
  at java.lang.Thread.sleep!(Native method)
  - sleeping on <0x2c930e32> (a java.lang.Object)
  at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Thread.java:1031)
  - locked <0x2c930e32> (a java.lang.Object)
  at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Thread.java:985)
  at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerWatchdogDaemon.sleepFor(Daemons.java:259)
  at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerWatchdogDaemon.waitForFinalization(Daemons.java:270)
  at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerWatchdogDaemon.run(Daemons.java:218)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Its very long and i am not able to understand if its a crash or ANR?
Above logs i got from

```
/data/anr/ folder
```

Anyone pls give me some pointers to debug this issue

Comment: ANRs happen when you block the UI thread for too long. Usually this means you're doing work on the UI thread that should be done in a background thread. I'd have to look at your codebase to know whether that's true, but you can read this for more info: https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/vitals/anr

Comment: After reading the above blog it seems like above crash is due to deadlock not ANR @Matt

Answer (score 0):

You can use this [ANR-WatchDog](https://github.com/SalomonBrys/ANR-WatchDog) library to get more detailed logs.